# RecordsetType property not found as a valid property in QueryDefs

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to lock my queries in my MS Access 2016 frontend, so that users see only a snapshot of the queries and are not able to edit the SQL code nor the data in the queries. However I run into problems with my VBA code:

```
'Lock queries
For Each oQD In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    'If Left(oQD.Name, 3) = "qry" Then
    If Left(oQD.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
        Set oProp = oQD.Properties("RecordsetType")
        If Err Then
            Set oProp = oQD.CreateProperty("RecordSource", dbText, "Snapshot")
            oQD.Properties.Append oProp
        Else
            oProp.Value = 2
        End If
    End If
Next oQD
```

which returns runtime error '3270': property not found for "RecordsetType". Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be to do with the fact that you have `Recordsource` rather than `RecordsetType` when creating the property?